# Can't upload file to server using FileTransfer

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to upload an image from my app to the server but it doesn't work. It always returns:

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "http_status": 405, // Method Not Allowed
}
```

**Ionic CLI Version:**  PRO 4.2.1

**Cordova Verion:**  8.0.0

**NPM Version:**  6.4.1

**Node.js version:**  8.11.3

**Platform:**  Android

Here is my code:

**TS File**

```
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();

    let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'name.jpg',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token
        }
    }

    fileTransfer.upload(imageData, apiUrl, options1)
    .then((data) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            message: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        alert.present();
    }, (err) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            message: JSON.stringify(err)
        });
        alert.present();
    });
```

**API URL**

```
    public function profilePicture(Request $request)
    {
        if(Input::file('file')){
            $newFileName = 'investor-'.strtolower(Auth::user()->first_name).'-'.date('m-d-Y-H-i-s').'.'.Input::file('file')->extension();
            $newFilePath = public_path('assets/images/investor/profile/');

            Input::file('file')->move($newFilePath,$newFileName);

            Investor::where('investor_id', Auth::user()->investor_id)->update([
                'profile_image' => 'assets/images/investor/profile/'.$newFileName,
            ]);
            HistoryController::createHistory('fund_investment', Auth::user()->investor_id); 

            return response()->json('success');
        } else {
            return response()->json('error');
        }
    }
```

---

*The weird thing is that the same code with a different API URL works on another function. I really don't know what is the problem. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance*

Comment: let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'name.jpg',
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + this.token
        }
    } 
      do not use "accept" in the header instead use 
      mimeType: "image/jpeg" in options1

Comment: I'll try this out. Thank you :)

Comment: @NasreenUstad, It didn't work either.

Comment: It seems to be one of two reasons. Either file transfer is unable to find the file - permission error, or the API endpoint in unable to accept it. Verify that both cases work.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @DelwynPinto, I tried to output and display the image and its path on the application and it successfully did the task. I also tried to change my url_api and it worked but that url_api is intended for another file upload function, the only weird thing is that I have the same code for both url_apis.:(

Comment: @D_N. I am getting ```code: 1``` error but when I tried to apply the solution of Nasreen, It returns the same error and a bunch of html and css code that came from my laravel api file.